# Picking a random element from a non-empty defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

Say I do:

```
import collections, random
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
d['foo'].append('bar')
```

Then I pick a random element:

```
random.choice(d)
```

Now let's print `d`:

```
defaultdict(list, {0: [], 'foo': ['bar']})
```

Why did `random.choice` add `0` as a key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internally this is what [`random.choice`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l273) does:

```
def choice(self, seq):
    """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]
```

As in your case the length was 1, after multiplication it would result in an number in range `[0.0, 1.0)` and after applying `int()`to it you will get 0.

Note that `defaultdict` will add any key to the dict that was accessed on it:

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> d['i dont exist']
[]
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'i dont exist': []})
```

Hence, your dict ended up with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behavior is actually *undefined*, because according to the document(emphasis mine):

> `random.choice(seq)`
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty
>   **sequence** seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

`seq` need to be a **sequence** type, such as `list`, `tuple` and `range`. However, `defaultdict` is a subclass of the built-in `dict` class, and thus it's a **mapping** type.

And since sequence types can only have integers as their "keys", it's not strange why `random.choice` would lookup `d[x]`, where `x` is an integer in `range(0, len(d))`.

Comment: I think it's a better answer since it explains using the correct terminology :  Python has a precise definition of what a sequence is, some container types aren't sequence (dict, sets).